# Catching the error when using SDK.REST to update a record

Tags: rest, sdk, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm attempting to use the SDK.REST method to update a record, however it isn't working and apart from putting some alerts on the success and failure functions i can't find out why it isn't working.

Is there a way that i can capture the actual error message that this would return?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the developer tools (F12) to set a breakpoint in the failure callback and inspect the xhr param for more info.  What are you seeing in the alert?  Post some code and error details if that doesn't help.

Comment: I'd completely forgot you could do this. I found that it was passing some incorrect data to the field I wanted to update, so i fixed that and it is working now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can turn on trace logging with this tool : http://crmdiagtool2011.codeplex.com/
(of course this doesn't work in CRM online)

Comment: I'd not seen this tool before, but it looks like it could be very useful. Thanks